# Grant Read/Write/Delete access via Apex Managed Sharing?

Tags: apex, customer-portal, sharing, apex-managed-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

Assume we have many groups of customer portal users and each group has an account that represents their company. We'd like each group of users to have full Read/Write/Delete access to each other's records, but no access to any other group's (account's) records. In all objects, each record has an external ID field that starts with a group-specific combination. We only want to share custom object records.

To accomplish this using Force.com Managed Sharing would entail manually creating a sharing rule per object per group while also maintaining a public group for each account which is quite cumbersome.

We would instead prefer to use Apex Managed Sharing to accomplish this. Looking at the docs, I see that the highest level of record access you can assign via Apex Managed Sharing is Read/Write. Is there absolutely no way to assign delete access?

How else might we implement this type of sharing structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible. If other permissions are already in place, a workaround for the delete problem is to create a custom controller with the delete operation and give it the `without sharing` modifier.